# Simple pendulum phase space plot with pgfplots: looking for a clever parameterization

Tags: pgfplots

I want to produce a nice phase space plot of the simple pendulum for a course I'm teaching. Essentially, this boils down to plotting `y^2/2 = cos(x) + e` for different values of `e` (the energy). If I solve for `y` and plot the resulting expression, then the curve appears broken near `y=0`. Solving for `x` and plotting the inverse function only moves the problem to `x=0`. Here's a MWE (for `e = -0.5`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=100] ({ acos(x^2/2+0.5)}, x);
  \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=100] ({-acos(x^2/2+0.5)}, x);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[domain=-60:60,samples=100] { sqrt(2*(cos(x)-0.5))};
  \addplot[domain=-60:60,samples=100] {-sqrt(2*(cos(x)-0.5))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm guessing there exists a clever parameterization for the curve that eliminates the problem, but so far have been unable to find it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The problem seems to be that the graph is broken, but simply increasing the number of samples solves that; e.g. samples=1200 for your the acos plot and samples=500 for the cos plot.

Comment: @DJP If it would be working well for nemarona as well, please, make your comment an answer to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way around those issues you mention in the comment above: use the `sagetex` package which give you the power of the CAS [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/index.html) to run the calculations. The code's probably not going to make much sense to you but all you'd need to do is change the value of e. By using the implicit plot function from Sage we don't need so many samples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
e = -.5
y,t = var('y,t')
f(x,y) = y^2-cos(x)
p = implicit_plot(f==e,(-4, 4),(-4, 4))
P = p.matplotlib()
R = P.get_children()[1]
S = R.collections[0]
r = S.get_paths()[0]
v = r.vertices
xvals = v[:,0]
yvals = v[:,1]

output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3]"
output += r"\addplot+[blue,mark size=0.17pt] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(xvals)):
    output += r"(%f, %f) "%(xvals[i],yvals[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\begin{sagesilent}
e = .8
y,t = var('y,t')
f(x,y) = y^2-cos(x)
p = implicit_plot(f==e,(-4, 4),(-4, 4))
P = p.matplotlib()
R = P.get_children()[1]
S = R.collections[0]
r = S.get_paths()[0]
v = r.vertices
xvals = v[:,0]
yvals = v[:,1]

output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3]"
output += r"\addplot+[blue,mark size=0.17pt] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(xvals)):
    output += r"(%f, %f) "%(xvals[i],yvals[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

You need Sage installed on your computer for the `sagetex` package to work OR with a (free) account at [SageMath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) you have access to Sage as you work in the cloud. Here is the code running on SageMath Cloud:[image]

If this is more of what you had in mind I can delete the first "answer".

Comment: This is definitely more than what I had in mind! I will give it a try.

Comment: Okay. I'll delete the previous answer.